# Wayland: How to start graphic application from TTY without display manager?

Tags: wayland

I'm not sure I have the right approach but...

With Xorg we could via xinit do things, but how to do that kind of thing with Wayland?

I'm just trying to launch from a TTY a graphics application without loading gnome or KDE (or other)...

I can not find anything on Google :(

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Try [cage](https://github.com/cage-kiosk/cage). If I understand, you're asking for a display server that runs a single client. This is known as a kiosk, and in Wayland it replaces the display server, window manager, and compositor with a single executable.

In other words, the Wayland desktop functions as a sort of `xinit`: there is no single implementation.